# Porque não é bom OR em um LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou criando uma `query` e minha `pull request` voltou porque o tester de código considerou que o `OR` não é bom para relacionamento de tabelas.

Exemplo:

```
  FROM LEFT JOIN administracao.cidade cid
    ON (cid.cid_cd_cidade = cec.cec_cd_cidade)
    OR (cid.cid_cd_cidade = cli.cli_cd_cidade)
```

O que recomendariam no lugar?

Comment: Eu faço consultas com `or` em junções, em casos bem específicos. Por exemplo, se eu posso chegar em um mesmo objeto através de mais de um caminho no relacionamento. Tipo o seu caso que você colocou, podendo chegar em `cid` através de `cec` ou de `cli`. Ele foi mais a fundo ou ficou só no achismo, o testador?

Answer (score 1):

Utilizar o `OR` com `LEFT JOIN`, deixa a `query` lenta, uma alternativa é usar o `UNION`.

```
  FROM LEFT JOIN administracao.cidade cid
    ON (cid.cid_cd_cidade = cec.cec_cd_cidade)
  UNION
  FROM LEFT JOIN administracao.cidade cid
    On (cid.cid_cd_cidade = cli.cli_cd_cidade)
```

Faça um teste realizando uma consulta, e observe o tempo de retorno, e cite nos comentários sua experiencia.

Comment: Realizarei aqui o teste, mas existe uma outra solução que me deram aqui.

Comment: Coloca como resposta também

Comment: Eu não sou fã de `UNION`s, prefiro `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver agora pouco, o tester fez desta forma:

```
  FROM LEFT JOIN administracao.cidade cid_cec
    ON cid_cec.cid_cd_cidade = cec.cec_cd_cidade
  LEFT JOIN administracao.cidade cid_cli
    ON cid_cli.cid_cd_cidade = cli.cli_cd_cidade
```

Comment: Devo dizer que essa consulta potencialmente não é a mesma da alternativa com o `UNION`, nem do `OR`. Acontece que aqui você adiciona mais um nível no produto cartesiano. O otimizador de consultas pode tratar isso corretamente, mas deixaria o trabalho dele mais pesado.